# Get array in a given format

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have an array as below.

```
let colors=[{id:"1",name:"red"},{id:"2",name:"green"}, 
           {id:"1",name:"blue"}];

what i expected is
let selectedColors={id: "1,2,3"};
```

please help me to get the ids in the above format.

Comment: You don't have a 3 in there, are you sure you want a "1,2,3"? I guess the "blue" id it's 3 then.

Comment: Yeah isn't the output `{id: "1,2,1"}` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Array Map function.

```js
let colors=[{id:"1",name:"red"},{id:"2",name:"green"}, 
           {id:"1",name:"blue"}];
let selectedColors = {id: colors.map((color) => color.id).join(',') }
console.log(selectedColors);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Array [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for this.

```js
let colors=[{id:"1",name:"red"},{id:"2",name:"green"}, 
           {id:"1",name:"blue"}];
           
let result = colors.reduce((acc, eachCol) => {
   if ('id' in acc) {
    acc.id = `${acc.id},${eachCol.id}`
   } else {
    acc.id = eachCol.id
   }
   return acc
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

By the help of java script map() mrthod you can achieve this functionality.

```
let colors=[{id:"1",name:"red"},{id:"2",name:"green"},{id:"1",name:"blue"}];

let selectedColors = colors.map((color) => color.id);
console.log(selectedColors);

output =  ["1", "2", "1"]
```